# How to Click the button in the table on specific row

Tags: java, selenium, button

I am new to Selenium IDE since I installed yesterday.
Anyway, I can't seem to figure out or to find solution for my problem;

I have a table on a webpage:

```
|name|description|something|delete button |
```

so I have several rows in the table and if click on the button delete it remembers its position  `xpath=(//a[contains(text(),'Delete')])[3]`
but i don't want it to remember to delete 3rd row but i want it to reference it to a name, so for instance if |name| is "tester" click on delete button in that same row.

I hope you understand my problem and can help me.

Comment: You should consider formatting your question with [SO markdown](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help). It helps possible answerers understand your question better and more easily.

Answer (score 2):

This can be easily achieved by [XPath](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/). There are lots of tutorials on it all over the web, try to take one. The spec is also a surprisingly good read!

Anyway, if your table row looked like this (I can't take a better guess based on data you provided):

```
<tr>
    <td class='name'>tester</td>
    <td class='description'>Some description</td>
    <td class='something'>Some text</td>
    <td class='actions'><a onclick="doSomething()">Delete</a></td>
</tr>
```

you would select the button based on the name like this:

```
//tr/td[@class='name' and text()='tester']/following-sibling::td/a[text()='Delete']
```

Selects:

1. any `<tr>`
2. then its `<td>` child with:

   - "class" attribute equal to "name"
   - inner text equal to "tester"
3. any following sibling of that `td`
4. then its `<a>` child with:

   - inner text equal to "Delete"